# Minor Bug in Keras: An incorrect rectification of ValueError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I trained a Keras model, however, I have difficulty in making it predict. My input array is of the shape `(400,2)` and the output array is of shape `(400,1)`. Now when I pass the argument `array([1,2])` to the `model.predict()` function, I get the following error:

```
 ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,).
```

**Which is nonsensical since `shape(array([1,2])) = (2,)` and hence the `model.predict` function should accept it as a valid input.**

On the contrary, when I pass an array of the shape `(1,2)` it works pristinely. So is there a bug in the Keras implementation?

My model is as follows:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(400,2)
Y = np.random.rand(400,1)

def base():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4,activation = 'tanh', input_dim = 2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr = 0.1), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])      
    return model 

model = base()
model.fit(data,Y, epochs = 10, batch_size =1)
model.predict(np.array([1,2]).reshape(2,1))   #Error
model.predict(np.array([1,2]).reshape(2,)) #Error
model.predict(np.array([1,2]).reshape(1,2)) #Works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first dimension is the batch dimension. Therefore you must pass an array with the shape of `(num_samples,) + (the input shape of network)` even when you use `predict` method. That's why when you pass an array with shape of `(1,2)` it works, since `(1,)` indicates the number of samples and `(2,)` is the input shape of network.

Answer (score 0):

If model is expecting (2,) array you should pass (2,) shape array

```
x = x.reshape((2,))
model.predict(x)
```

Comment: And I did. array([2,1]) has the shape (2,) and yet I got an error